# Find an injection from $\mathbb{Z_+}^n \to \mathbb{Z_+}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, notation

> Find an injection from $\mathbb{Z_+}^n \to \mathbb{Z_+}$

This is what I did. Define $f : \mathbb{Z_+}^n \to \mathbb{Z_+}$ such that

$$f\left(((x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z_+}}\right) = x_1$$

If I scrapped the notation, it would essentially be the following function  $f((x_1, x_2, \ldots)) = x_1$

Would this function define an injection? Furthermore, I'm not sure if I've made correct use of notation?

Is there are better, cleaner way of finding an injective function mapping $\mathbb{Z_+}^n \to \mathbb{Z_+}$?

Comment: It seems the function you are describing would actually be mapping out of $(\mathbb{Z}^n)^n)$, but it looks like Seth addresses this in his answer

Comment: Aside from that, take n to be 3, according to your map (1,2,3) --> 1 and (1,2,2) --> 1. Check your definition of injection and see if this satisfies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ be distinct primes and consider $f((x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n)) = p_1^{x_1} p_2^{x_2} \cdots p_n^{x_n}$.

Comment: they will be any case for this type of application to be bijective, yes ?

Comment: To OP, if you pursue this map as a candidate for your injection be sure to formally prove it from the definition of injective you have.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you actually want is

$$f((x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n)) = x_1.$$

This seems to be what you are trying to say, but you need to remember that elements of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ are single elemements, and elements of $\mathbb{Z}_+^n$ are vectors. (It looks like you were treating it like elements of $\mathbb{Z}_+$ were vectors, and elements of $\mathbb{Z}_+^n$ were vectors of vectors.)

Comment: and important to note: this is **not injective**.

Comment: @setholopolus, Yep sorry, made a couple of mistakes in my post, this was what I was referring to

Answer (score 3):

If we consider on $\mathbb{Z}^n$ the lexicographic order that mean 
$$
x\leq_{\mathbb{Z}^n}y \qquad \iff x_1<y_1 \; \text{ Or } x_1=y_1 \; \rm{ and } \; x_2<y_2 \dots
$$ 
we can see that this will be a total order on $\mathbb{Z}^n$, so if we put 
$$
f: \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}\\
$$
Which associate $f(0)=0$ and to each $x$ its position for this order, this map will be injective.